# MSSQL Certification 70-432

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

I work for a small software company and once I'm certified in implementing and maintaining MSSQL, I have the opportunity to move over to implementation from support.

My question is what do you suggest as good resources, practice tests etc to prepare. I currently have limited knowledge in SQL, I'm able to write basic query's, backup and restore databases etc. I am currently working my way through the free modules in Microsoft's E-learning center and I have also the MCTS Self Paced Training Kit for Exam 70-432. Does any one have any direct experience taking the cert, if so what all did you use for study materials and practice exams?

Once I feel I'm ready the company is going to pay fro my certification, I just want to make sure I pass it the first time. I want to be well prepared and know my stuff not just what is contained in the exam.

Thanks for the assistance and information.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/exam-resources-for-70-432/): in particular take note of the second-chance offers.

Answer (score 0):

The exams are designed to show that you have real world experience with the product, not basic knowledge.  How long have you been working with the product for?

That said, I worked on at book for the 70-432.  The ISBN is 1597494208 and you can find it on Amazon. [http://www.amazon.com/Real-MCTS-Server-2008-70-432/dp/1597494208/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpt_3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1597494208)

Comment: I used the MS Press book which had quite a few mistakes and required extra reading to cover some areas. Also end of chapter questions where out of sync with the chapter content. Haven't used the book that mrdenny worked on but it's got to better than the MS one.

Comment: I do hate hearing that about the MS Press books (or really any book).  The MS Press books are supposed to match the exam information pretty well.  I guess they fubar'd that one up.  I know that some of the MS Press books which I've read in the past were quite good.

Comment: I used MS Press books for learning Windows 2000 systems and the books were great for learning, although I never took any tests.  That's not to say they haven't gone downhill since then.

Answer (score 0):

Measure Up are pretty good for practice exams and you get a free study crib sheet. I printed this out and covered the other sides with my own notes too. Was pretty useful for the more focused cramming in the lead up the exam (and just before).

http://www.measureup.com/